# Handle large numbers with precision in Redis Lua

Tags: lua, redis, largenumber

I need to handle large numbers in Lua which goes with Redis. Normally you would do that like:

```
require"bc"
bc.mul(...)
bc.mod(...)
```

etc.
But unfortunately Redis Lua doesn't support "require". The only approach I've found is inserting a large numbers library written in lua itself directly into the script.

The only such library I could get my hands on: [oss.digirati.com.br/luabignum/index.htm](http://oss.digirati.com.br/luabignum/index.htm)

I can strip the library for the purposes of a concrete script but it still remains huge. Is there any way to handle large numbers in Redis Lua more efficiently?

**UPDATE1:** What if I save the whole library into a key and then access it like:

```
local BigNumLib = KEYS[1];
BigNumLib.BigNum.mul(KEYS[2],KEYS[3]);
```

I'm not sure of the syntax and perhaps I'll need to enclose all the library in a lua table {}.

Comment: I don't think there is a convenient solution here, except by tweaking Redis source code itself.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with how Redis handles Lua code, but why is inserting the library itself into your code is a problem? you should be able to do something like this:

```
local bc = function()
  -- insert the code of BigNum.lua here
  return BigNum
end
bc.mul(....)
```

The code has probably been written before Lua 5.1, so I don't know if there are any compatibility issues, but this should at least give you a start.

Comment: It's a problem because every request with the library in it will be 25 KB.

Comment: Not necessarily, because you can use EVALSHA. The first request will be 25 KB, the following ones will be only a few bytes. You will save some bandwidth. However, the Lua engine will have to interpret 25 KB of data at each execution, yes.

Comment: @MidnightCoder, you may trim the code only leaving those methods you need.